# Standard error file when there is no error

Tags: linux

I'm new to Linux & shell and I'm struggling with checking if the compilation is successful.

```
g++ code.cpp -o code.o 2>error.txt
if [ ! -e error.txt ]
then
  do something
else
  echo "Failed to compile"
```

I guess an error file is created even if the compilation is successful. What is the content of the error file when there is no error? I need to change the if condition to check if the compilation is successful.

Comment: just check the return code in `$?`...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just the order of things.  What happens when the shell parses the string `g++ code.cpp -o code.o 2>error.txt` is:

1. The shell creates `error.txt`, truncating the file if that name already exists.
2. `g++` is called with its error output redirected to the new file.

If `g++` does not write any data, then the file remains as it was (empty) at the end of step 1.

You probably aren't so much interested in the error file as you are the return value.  You probably ought to just do:

```
if g++ code.cpp -o code; then : do something; done
```

or even just:

```
g++ code .cpp -o code && : do something
```

but if really want to do something else with the errors, you can do:

```
if g++ code.cpp -o code.o 2> error.txt; then
    rm error.txt
    : do something
else
    echo >&2 Failed to compile code.cpp.\  See "$(pwd)"/error.txt for details.
fi
```

Make sure you escape at least one of the spaces after the `.` so that you get 2 spaces after the period (or just quote the whole argument to `echo`).  Although it's become fashionable lately to claim that you only need one space, all of those arguments rely on the use of variable width fonts and any command line tool worth using will be used most often in an environment where fixed width fonts are still dominant.  This last point is totally unrelated to your question, but is worth remembering.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I actually needed to do something only when the compilation is successful. Since you told me the error file will be empty in that case, I used if [ ! -s error.txt ] and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: @suzz.  No!  Don't do that.  Just do `if g++...`

Comment: Oki I'll do that :)